# Python + Google App Engine: os.path.exist only finds *some* files

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm using djangoappengine (https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine) and boot.py's find_project_dir doesn't find app.yaml.

I'm adding this debug code and run it with AppEngine Launcher 1.9.9.1194, and SDK 1.9.9 timestamp 1406573704.

**Note: This may have worked with older versions of the AppEngine SDK.**  I didn't touch the project in quite a while and when I touched it again I had this problem. There was a SDK update in between.

I fixed it for now checking for cron.yaml instead of app.yaml, but that doesn't explain why this occurs. In case this occurs to more people I'd file a bug.

```
for d in os.listdir('/path/to/my/project/'):
    print d
    print os.path.exists('/path/to/my/project/%s' % d)
```

Output:

```
.DS_Store
False
.gaedata
False
.git
False
.gitignore
False
__init__.py
True
__init__.pyc
False
app.yaml
False
autoload
True
build.sh
True
cron.yaml
True
csrfsetmiddleware
True
customers
True
dbindexer
True
django
True
djangoappengine
True
djangoappengine_git
True
djangoappengine_old
True
djangotoolbox
True
djangotoolbox_git
True
djangotoolbox_old
True
frontend
False
index.yaml
False
indexes.py
True
indexes.pyc
False
invoices
True
LICENSE
True
manage.py
True
README.md
True
requirements.txt
True
services
True
settings.py
True
settings.pyc
False
static_frontend
True
templates
True
urls.py
True
urls.pyc
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the path you're passing to `listdir`, this is a simulation of what would happen once you upload the app. Certain of those files are skipped due to `skip_files` in `app.yaml`, and `app.yaml` is consulted during upload, but isn't actually present and readable by a deployed application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is this something that changed in recently?

Comment: Things do change occasionally as new features are added or bugs are fixed. What are you seeing now that you suspect is incorrect?